# Set sale price on Variable Products without making them out of stock in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($loop->posts as $product) {
$currentPrice = get_post_meta($product->ID, '_regular_price', true);
update_post_meta( $product->ID, '_price', $currentPrice );
update_post_meta( $product->ID, '_regular_price', $currentPrice );  

delete_metadata('post', $product->ID, '_sale_price');
if(in_array($i, $random_product)) {
    $discount = rand(10,25) / 100;
    $salePrice = $discount * $currentPrice;
    $salePrice = ceil($currentPrice - $salePrice);
    if($salePrice == $currentPrice) {
        $salePrice = $currentPrice - 1;
    }
    if($currentPrice != '' || $currentPrice == '0') {
        update_post_meta($product->ID, '_sale_price', $salePrice);
        update_post_meta( $product->ID, '_price', $salePrice );
        echo "Sale Item $i / Product ID $product->ID / Current Price $currentPrice / Sale Price $salePrice \n"; 
    }
}
$i++;
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is take every item through my store, loop it and if it's in my array (which is just a random generated array of product IDs) it should set those to be on sale, and make sure every other product is not on sale.

However, when I do that... for whatever reason all my variable products then show up as unavailable until I go into their product page and click Variations -> Set Status -> In Stock

I thought I would be clever and change it to managed stock and have 999 products available in stock but still creates the same problem.

The thing is, I don't change the stock with this only the price... however it is this code I have run it manually and it triggers the problem.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use [CRUD methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) newly introduced since WooCommerce 3 instead of using WordPress post meta functions.

I have also made some changes in your code, But is not possible to test that as your question code is incomplete. Try something like the following:

```
foreach ( $loop->posts as $post ) {
    // Get an instance of the product object
    $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
    
    $changes = false;

    // Get product regular and sale prices
    $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
    $sale_price    = $product->get_sale_price();
    
    if( ! empty($sale_price) || $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        // Empty product sale price
        $product->set_sale_price('');

        // Set product active price back to regular price
        $product->set_price($regular_price);
        
        $changes = true;
    }
    
    if( in_array( $i, $random_product ) ) {
        // Calculate a ramdom sale price for the current ramdom product
        $discount_rate = (100 - rand(10, 25)) / 100;
        $sale_price    = ceil($discount_rate * $regular_price);

        // Set product active price and sale price
        $product->set_sale_price($sale_price);
        $product->set_price($sale_price);

        printf( __("Sale Item %s / Product ID %s / Current Price %s / Sale Price %s \n"),
        $i, $post->ID, wc_price($regular_price), wc_price($sale_price) );
        
        $changes = true;
    }
    $i++;
    
    if( $changes ){
        // Save the product data
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Untested

Comment: Thank you so much, I haven't had a chance to actually test this, I will later today but this is a far better and less hacky looking solution than what I had. I also feel dumb not thinking of the $changes = true bit